# Java I/O how many Objects are in the file?

Tags: java, io, stream

I'm trying to save a a list of personnel in a `.txt` file using the `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
public void writeUsers(List<Personnel> userList)    {
    userSize = userList.size();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(userFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        for (Personnel user : userList){
            oos.writeObject(user);
        }
        oos.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To read the file I use the following method:

```
public List<Personnel> readUsers()  {
    List<Personnel> userList = new ArrayList<Personnel>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(userFile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        for(int i = 0; i < userSize; i++){
            System.out.println("Entering loop"); 
            userList.add((Personnel)ois.readObject()); 
        }
        System.out.println(userList.size());
        ois.close();
        fis.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

My problem is that I can't read an existing file with the read method without using the `writeUser()` method before because of the attribute `userSize` that is defined in `writeUser()` and then used in the loop in `readUser()`.

```
 for(int i=0; i < userSize; i++)
```

Is there something I can do to get the quantity of objects in my file?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [ObjectInputStream readObject in while Loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/33135298)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop until you get an EndOfFile Exception:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        userList.add((Personnel) ois.readObject()); 
    } catch (EOFException e) {
         // end of file reached
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: don't loop. Just write the entire collection as a single object, and read it back ditto.